# invalid literal for int() with base 10: in python

Tags: python

I am taking a python course on www.adex.org. During course exercise I need to write a code for the following.

**Exercise: Write a function that accepts a number as argument and returns the square of the number. For example if the number passed to the function is 5 then your function should return 25.**

**I have written the following code**

```
def mysquare(n):

  result = n**2

  return result

a = int(input("Please enter the number: "))

print (mysquare(a))
```

**Error Message:**
Error in executing student function:

> ValueError at line 4
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

The same code is working fine in python IDLE but not working fine on adex.org's editor. Any idea what could be reason for this error?

Comment: You didn't enter anything in the editor

Comment: Based on how the question is worded, I don't think your code is supposed to parse user input.

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Many thanks I just realized it and wrote the following short code which just worked out.

def mysquare(a):

  return a**2

print (mysquare(5))

Answer (score 0):

You were not handling the condition where a wrong input that is other than integer is provided. Try this. It will fix your issue as till such user fulfills the requirements it will not be allowed to move forward :

```
def mysquare(n):
    result = n**2
    return result
while True :
    try :
        a = int(input("Please enter the number: "))
        break
    except :
        print("You provided wrong data. Try again.")

print (mysquare(a))
```

Comment: Explain yourself please. Don't just dump code like that

Comment: I have not read try and except yet and also I got the following error in their editor stdout: '', stderr: 'sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-2-12-214

Comment: @Naveed : There is no need to worry if you haven't reached till exception handling yet. Just use the code for a while and if possible try to make sense of it. If you are facing any other issue just use command line input to validate your code sample. Let me know if any help required.